# Find the Mistakes in This Sentence

Tags: traducción

Tengo la siguiente oración de un texto que estoy traduciendo:

*Él,como pudo, midío en diferentes días y a diferentes horas*

¿Cuales son los problemas de esta oración? ¿Cómo puedo rehacerla?

---

I have the following sentence from a document I am translating:

*Él,como pudo, midío en diferentes días y a diferentes horas*

What are some problems in this sentence. How would you rewrite it?

Comment: I cannot really help you without knowing the original sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The word *midío* is wrong, it should be *midió*. Also, it is not *oracíon* but *oración*.

That is the only mistake I see. I am a native spanish speaker, and the sentence makes sense to me.

Comment: I would reorder it as _Él midió como pudo en diferentes días y a diferentes horas_, I could use _distintos/as_ en lugar de _diferentes_ in one or both occurences. But, besides accentuation mistakes, I agree the sentence is okay as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What originally bothered me was that we had two conjugated verbs together, 'pudo' and 'midió'.

Answer (score 0):

As Juan Sebastian states, modulo the bad spelling of *midío*, which should be *midió*, the sentence is correct. It means,

> *He measured, as he could, on different days, at different times.*